# MassTransit/RabbitMQ - Moving rejected messages to dead letter w/ redelivery

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

I'm currently working on a project where we would like the use a dead-letter queue for message redelivery instead of the built-in scheduler of MassTransit.

The idea is simple: If a consumer throws a certain set of exceptions we retry the message several times and then want to re-schedule the message for re-delivery in the (near) future. For instance, if messages arrive in the wrong order. I am trying to accomplish option #2 from this article ( https://engineering.nanit.com/rabbitmq-retries-the-full-story-ca4cc6c5b493 )

Whenever my consumer throws an exception, MassTransit will move the message to the _error queue instead of the dead letter. I'm sure this is a misconfiguration on my part but I'm not really sure how I can accomplish what I want.

My bus is configured like this:

```
IBusControl ConfigureBus(IBusRegistrationContext provider)
{
    return Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(sbc =>
    {
        sbc.Host("localhost", c =>
        {
            c.Username("guest");
            c.Password("guest");
        });

        sbc.MessageTopology.SetEntityNameFormatter(new EntityNameFormatter("Consumer1"));

        sbc.ReceiveEndpoint("Consumer1.ActionPerformed", ep =>
        {
            ep.Consumer<ActionPerformedConsumer>();
            ep.ExchangeType = ExchangeType.Fanout;

            ep.UseMessageRetry(r => r.Immediate(1));
            ep.BindDeadLetterQueue("deadletter", "dead", cfg =>
            {
                cfg.SetExchangeArgument("x-message-ttl", TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
                cfg.Durable = true;
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To change the error queue behavior of MassTransit, you can configure the receive endpoint to propagate errors back up to the transport, which will nack them back to the broker.

```
ep.RethrowFaultedMessages();
```

However, I'm pretty sure MassTransit does this with the `requeue` parameter set to `true` so that under normal conditions messages are not lost. I don't believe there is currently a way to override it.

It would seem that if this is an approach that works (of course, it won't work with quorum queues, they don't support TTL) with standard queues, it might be worth adding this type of configuration to RabbitMQ so that it builds out the exchanges and such to handle it as an alternative to the delayed exchange scheduler.

> Update, I'd consider Option 3 superior to Option 2, and more inline with how MassTransit works.

Comment: Hello @Chris Patterson, is there any follow up on this one? I would very much like to leverage this approach for redelivery, instead of DLX-based, since using that plugin is not an option for my case. I would appreciate any further guidance.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson can you comment on what (if anything) about this answer is different when using MT 8.x with RabbitMQ 3.10+? (N.B. quorum queues now support message TTL)